# Latex "element of with two strokes" (⋹)

Tags: symbols, mathjax

Is there a latex symbol akin to `\in`, but with two strokes? It has a Unicode equivalent, `⋹`. I looked on detexify, but I couldn't find anything that matched. If it doesn't exist, how might I "rig" it?

### Edit

The solutions posted do work, but I also now find the need to have a MathJax version of the symbol. I am not sure as to how to include the solutions given in a MathJax define key; using the usual "macros" produces an error.

### Enlarged image

[image: enlarged symbol]

Comment: You mean the Euro symbol?

Comment: @cfr No, it _does_ look like the Euro symbol, but it is specifically an element membership symbol with two strokes down the center.

Comment: How very confusing. I see now that it is not quite the same but it really looks like it without a magnifying glass!

Comment: @cfr, Haha, right! I added a larger picture for those of who are without magnifying glasses.

Comment: Very useful. It is now clearly a not-quite-but-confusingly-similar-to-a-Euro symbol ;). Do you know what it is called or what is it used for? That might give somebody an idea (although not me).

Comment: For MathJax, why not just use the Unicode character directly?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sorry, yes, of course.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's one option using `\ooalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\Inn{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$\subset$\cr\hfil\scalebox{0.8}[1]{$=$}\hfil\cr}}%
}
\begin{document}

\[
A\in B
\]

\[
A\Inn B
\]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

And if you need it for the different math styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\Inn{%
  \mathrel{\mathchoice
    {\ooalign{$\displaystyle\subset$\cr\hfil\scalebox{0.8}[1]{$=$}\hfil\cr}}%
    {\ooalign{$\textstyle\subset$\cr\hfil\scalebox{0.8}[1]{$\textstyle=$}\hfil\cr}}%
    {\ooalign{$\scriptstyle\subset$\cr\hfil\scalebox{0.8}[1]{$\scriptstyle=$}\hfil\cr}}%
    {\ooalign{$\scriptscriptstyle\subset$\cr\hfil\scalebox{0.8}[1]{$\scriptscriptstyle=$}\hfil\cr}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
A\in B\quad{\textstyle A\in B}\quad  L_{A\in B}\quad  M_{L_{A\in B}}
\]

\[
A\Inn B\quad{\textstyle A\Inn B}\quad  L_{A\Inn B}\quad M_{L_{A\Inn B}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

It's Unicode symbol U+22F9 "Element of with two horizontal strokes": ⋹.

When LuaTeX or XeTeX is used, then the symbol is available with the following fonts:

- **Asana Math**

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}

  \begin{document}
  \[ A \isinE B \]
  \end{document}
  ```

  > [image: Result Asana Math]
- **XITS Math**

  ```
  \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
  ```

  > [image: Result XITS Math]
- The Latin Modern Math or TeX Gyre Math fonts do not have the symbol.

Answer (score 7):

This uses a stack, and will work in all mathstyles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine,scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Inn{\def\stackalignment{c}\def\stacktype{L}\ThisStyle{\mathrel{%
  \stackon[0pt]{$\SavedStyle\subset$}{\scalebox{0.86}[1]{$\SavedStyle=$}}}}%
}
\begin{document}

\[
A\in B
\]

\[
A\Inn B\quad
\scriptstyle A\Inn B\quad
\scriptscriptstyle A\Inn B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]